# Why does my web site prompt for a username password when custom errors mode is on

Tags: asp.net

While navigating my site with custom errors mode set to off it behaves normal. If I turn I turn custom errors mode to on, then my first visit to the site prompts me with a username password dialog box.

The entire site is enforced with SSL if that matters. Where should I start looking? Is this possibly an IIS issue? I'm not sure why setting custom errors mode to on/off would invoke this type of behavior.

Comment: You can use Firebug and the Net tab to see which resources (Image, Script, etc) might be giving a 403 or 401. It might not be the page at all, just something else the page is trying to load (i.e. do you have to enter the username and password for it to work, or does hitting cancel let it continue anyway?)

Comment: @vcsjones, hitting cancel works. But I don't want users thinking they can't use the website unless the login to this prompt. I'm not sure what even owns this prompt(what username and password is it expecting)?

Comment: @Nick using Firebug and the Net tab will likely tell you what is causing this.

Comment: Make sure your custom errors page is accessible to everyone.

Comment: I'm using the Net tab, I cleared the cache and took a look at the HTTP requests- everything is 200 OK. @gbs, the custom errors page is a public page like most of the others.

Comment: I have no idea. This was happening yesterday, and then I came back today after posting this, set custom errors back to On, and it's not coming up anymore. Maybe I had a an HTTP error yesterday and I fixed it without realizing it?

Comment: @Nick fun! At least it is working now.